# How can I replace the WM_CONCAT function in this query? [ORA-00904: "WM_CONCAT": invalid identifier]

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to run a monitoring query on an Oracle DB via the jdbc input from Logstash, but I'm getting this error:

> [WARN ][logstash.inputs.jdbc     ][main][1ec4a1ad09c5010bbf85f526e65df211d70574bd55d36b00b9db2ee4113dbe6d] Exception when executing JDBC query {:exception=>"Java::JavaSql::SQLSyntaxErrorException: **ORA-00904: "WM_CONCAT": invalid identifier**"}

It seems that the WM_CONCAT function is not supported in the new Oracle versions anymore.

This is the query I was trying to run:

```
SELECT /*+ ORDERED */ gvw.sid as waiting_session, gvw.INST_ID as WAITING_SESSION_inst_id, GVWS.SQL_ID waiting_sql_id, gvws.OSUSER waiting_osuser,gvws.MACHINE  waiting_machine, gvws.PROGRAM waiting_program, gvh.SID as holding_session, GVH.INST_ID as HOLDING_SESSION_inst_id, (SELECT DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR (wm_concat (b.sql_id), 4000) sql_ids
FROM gv$open_cursor a, gv$SQLTEXT_WITH_NEWLINES b, gV$SQLCOMMAND c
WHERE     a.sid = gvh.SID
   AND a.inst_id = GVH.INST_ID
   AND a.sql_id = b.sql_id
   AND a.inst_id = b.inst_id
   AND a.inst_id = c.inst_id
   AND a.hash_value = b.hash_value
   AND command_name IN ('INSERT', 'UPDATE', 'DELETE')
   AND c.command_type = b.command_type
   AND UPPER (b.sql_text) LIKE '%' || do.object_name || '%')  holding_sqls_id, 
    gvhs.OSUSER holding_osuser,gvhs.MACHINE  holding_machine, gvhs.PROGRAM holding_program,
           su.username,                                        
           do.object_name,                                     
           do.object_type,                                     
           gvws.SECONDS_IN_WAIT                            
        FROM gv$lock gvh,                                  
                 gv$lock gvw,                                  
                 gv$session gvws,         
                 gv$session gvhs,                      
                 dba_objects do,                               
                 dba_users su                                  
           WHERE  gvh.id1 = gvw.id1                            
                 AND gvh.id2 = gvw.id2                         
                 and gvh.TYPE = 'TM'                         
                 and gvw.TYPE = 'TM'                         
                 and gvws.sid =  gvw.sid                       
                 and gvws.inst_id =gvw.inst_id                 
                 and gvws.BLOCKING_INSTANCE = gvh.inst_id      
                 and gvws.BLOCKING_SESSION = gvh.sid     
                 and gvws.BLOCKING_INSTANCE = gvhs.inst_id      
                 and gvws.BLOCKING_SESSION = gvhs.sid                                
                 AND gvh.id1 = do.object_id                    
                 AND su.username = do.owner                                   
union all
SELECT 
0 as waiting_session,       
0 as WAITING_SESSION_inst_id,    
'N/A'  WAITING_SQL_ID,
'N/A'  WAITING_OSUSER,
'N/A'  WAITING_MACHINE,       
'N/A'  WAITING_PROGRAM,        
0 as holding_session,                            
0 as HOLDING_SESSION_inst_id,    
'N/A'  HOLDING_SQLS_ID,
'N/A'  HOLDING_OSUSER,
'N/A'  HOLDING_MACHINE,  
'N/A'  HOLDING_PROGRAM,               
'N/A' as username,                                        
'N/A' as object_name,                                     
'N/A' as object_type,                                     
-1 as SECONDS_IN_WAIT 
FROM dual
```

Can anyone help me with a workaround?

Comment: "It seems that the WM_CONCAT function is not supported in the new Oracle versions anymore" - [it was never supported](https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocContentDisplay?id=1336219.1) Just putting "wm_concat" into a search engine brings back lots of information on alternatives; including [this summary](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/string-aggregation-techniques). There are lots of variations on the question on this site too.

Comment: Your last link helped me a lot. I was able to replace the wm-concat function without knowing SQL. Very helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We use `LISTAGG` nowadays, e.g.

```
SQL> select deptno,
  2         listagg(ename, ',') within group (order by ename) list_of_employees
  3  from emp
  4  group by deptno;

    DEPTNO LIST_OF_EMPLOYEES
---------- ----------------------------------------
        10 CLARK,KING,MILLER
        20 ADAMS,FORD,JONES,SCOTT,SMITH
        30 ALLEN,BLAKE,JAMES,MARTIN,TURNER,WARD

SQL>
```

`wm_concat` was undocumented, you shouldn't have used it anyway.